# What SplitButton does Microsoft use in Visual Studio for the IDE toolbar if they are not part of WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

From searching around, it looks like there aren't any SplitButtons for Windows Presentation Foundation. There are a couple commercial options, but don't want to bother with licensing. Does anyone know how Microsoft is accomplishing this for their toolbar on Visual Studio?

Comment: Takes a morning to write one in WPF. Also, this is off topic.

Comment: @EdPlunkett : why is it off topic? what am I missing? (besides a brain to figure out why this is off topic of course) Thanks.

Comment: @Arjang Seems to me it's not a question about programming. If I'm the only one who sees it that way, no harm done.

Comment: @EdPlunkett : no  you are not alone, in the past I have asked similar questions and was pointed out that is off topic. I don't know where to ask questions like this one either.

Comment: What's a good place to post this question and get an answer?

Comment: @Michael Weston, that is a good question, I too am interested in finding out more about tools and components used by different products, Maybe visual studio blog (if there is such a thing) . BTW I thought Michael Weston was the pseudonym used by a group of people to wreak havoc. :)

Comment: Using Snoop, the button is hosted in a Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsToolBarPanel and the button itself is a Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsButton. Maybe try: Add Reference->Assemblies->Extensions->Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop. Not sure if you can distribute that though... looks like part of VS.